# UITableView isn't appearing in view?

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

My `tableview` isn't loading once I press build, can anyone see what's wrong with the code as to why it's not showing up? In the console, it's printing the data from `Firestore`, but I can't see anything on the simulator but a white screen.

```
struct Posts {
   var caption:String
}

class CoursesVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

let tableView = UITableView()

var posts = [Posts]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    setupViews()
       
       loadPosts()

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func loadPosts() {
    let dbUsers = Firestore.firestore().collection("Payouts")
    dbUsers.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            for document in (querySnapshot?.documents)! {
                if let Caption = document.data()["amount"] as? String {
                    print(Caption)
                    var post = Posts(caption: "")
                    post.caption = Caption

                    self.posts.append(post)
                }

            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            print(self.posts)
        }
    }
  }

private func setupViews() {
let stackView: UIStackView = {
    let sv = UIStackView()
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sv.spacing = 28
    sv.axis = .vertical
    sv.distribution = .fill
    sv.alignment = .fill
    return sv
    }()
    
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    view.addSubview(tableView)

}
}

extension CoursesVC: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
let post = posts[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = post.caption
return cell
}
}
```

Comment: where did you assign `@IBOutlet` of `UITableView` ?

Comment: It's at the very top on the code I posted "let tableView = UITableView()"

Comment: Have you used Storyboard to insert TableView or you're just doing it programmatically ?
Also ..show your Cell File

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to assign frame to your tableView. As you are adding your tableView programatically so, you have to set frame for your tableView. Write below code in your `setupViews()` method.

E.g. `tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 450.0)`

Change tableView frame as per your requirement.

Comment: That's giving me an error - "Thread 1: Exception: "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard"

Comment: Exactly you have to create XIB for your tableView cell and return that cell in cellForRowAt indexPath.